# Powershell getchild-item by specific date

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find files from the previous day to copy, but my simple get-childitem isn't working. It works with every other switch except -eq.  Any suggestions to list files only from the previous day ?

get-childitem c:\users| where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -eq (get-date).adddays(-2)}

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for files that are written at exact time ( hours mins, secs, year, month and 2 days before). Unless the files were written to the second, two (or one) days ago, you will not find them. In other words, you were comparing full `DateTime` objects and not just a date and hence there is very less chance that they were exactly equal, which seemed to suggest that `-eq` doesn't work, but other comparisons do.

You probably wanted to just compare the dates, without the times:

```
$yesterday = (get-date).AddDays(-1).Date
gci c:\users | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $yesterday}
```

( also moved the get-date outside, as you probably don't want to do it again and again.)

Comment: I think you meant to pipe the output of gci into the Where-Object cmdlet, not ForEach-Object (?, not %).

Answer (score 1):

They are not *equal* because they differ in time. If you want an exact date match, use the Date property:

```
get-childitem c:\users| where-object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (get-date).adddays(-2).Date}
```